# How to update the remote tracking branch to a specific commit?

Tags: git

Given:

- 2 fulls local clones of the same repository - clone A and clone B
- clone A was refreshed from remote relatively recently
- clone B is old

I would like to bring the clone B to the same state as clone A with as little network traffic to/from the remote as possible. However, I do not want to just copy over the A\.git folder over B\.git - I want to do it using the proper git commands.

So far I run (assume the A and B folders correspond to the A and B clones):

```
B> git fetch ../A
B> git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

So that puts the master branch of B at the same commit as the master branch of A. However, **origin/master** in B is NOT the same as in A.

And hence is my question - how can I update the **origin/master** in B?

Of course, I can run `git fetch origin`, but then **origin/master** in B is likely to "overshoot", because the remote repository is likely to have more commits than is currently found in A.

I thought the following commands would work (this is Powershell):

```
git checkout -q (git rev-parse HEAD)
git fetch origin "$(git rev-parse HEAD):master"
git checkout master
```

Alas, the git fetch command does not update **origin/master**. I also tried with a temporary branch:

```
git branch -f temp
git push -uq origin temp:temp
git checkout temp
git fetch origin temp:master
git checkout master
```

Same result - **origin/master** is unchanged.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have not tried this, but perhaps you could completely avoid network traffic by creating a git patch file in local repo A and applying it in local repo B to the remote tracking branches. If that fits into your constraints of "normal git commands", that is

Comment: Could you provide an answer with the concrete commands? I would like to understand how exactly it modifies **origin/master**.

Comment: I just gave it a try and while _creating_ a patch for `origin/master` worked flawlessly, applying it did not. However, I just had a new idea. I'm not really clear on your use case requirements, but what about adding a new remote to `A` that is  just a local folder? I'll testrun this quickly and then write the steps as an answer so you can see if it's what you want

Comment: If that's not what you need, then I think some more context about the usecase could be helpful for anybody thinking of a good solution

Comment: Consider running `git fetch` from A in B, so that you have the objects. Then run `git fetch`. Something else to remember for some future cases is `git clone --reference` (when using this, read the documentation carefully, especially the section on the related `--dissociate` option).

Comment: @torek - but I did run `git fetch ../A` from B - it is in my post at the very top. Then I hard reset to `FETCH_HEAD`. This way `master` became the same in the two repos. However, in A `master` = `origin/master`, but in B `origin/master` is not. And that is what I want to fix.

Comment: I was just talking about how to avoid sending traffic over the network. Once you have the objects, it's just a matter of fiddling with your names. Git doesn't *care* about the names, Git *cares* about the *objects*. Make the names you want point to the objects you want and you're done.

Comment: @torek - but how do I advance `origin/master` to catch up to `master`?

Comment: `origin/master` is just your local Git's memory of some other Git's `master` (the Git over at `origin`). So if their `master` is up to date, run `git fetch origin`. You won't get any *objects* this time (as you have them already) but your Git will automatically update your `origin/*` remote-tracking *names*.

Comment: @torek - I want to synchronize with A (which is another full clone) and not with the remote. The remote may be beyond A and so if I execute `git fetch origin` it would bring changes I do not need and set `origin/master` beyond `master`. No, I want to sync exactly with A, including `origin/master` to be aligned with what it is in A.

Comment: Then set `origin` to refer to `A`, and run `git fetch origin` and you're done. But what do you want to do over on the Git repository that you're *currently* calling `origin`? Nothing?

Comment: Nothing. I just want the two clones to point at the same master, including their respective remote tracking branches. And they should have the same origin - the original remote repo.

Answer (score 0):

#### Approach Outline

We create a remote repository in another local directory. Repository `A` pushes its branches to there, repository `B` fetches from there. This way, the actual state of the upstream repository is irrelevant for this transaction. You get a new remote repository with the state you want.

This does not *modify* the state of `origin/master`, it only adds a new remote that has the correct state though. So perhaps this is not exactly what you want. (I only realized that halfway through, hence I wrote the answer anyway)

#### Test Setup

We have two repositories and some upstream remote repository that already exist. `upstream` might be e.g. on some github server. For this answer, I will use a local folder to simulate it, but that does not matter much.

```sh
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g$ git init B
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/generic/Downloads/g/B/.git/
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g$ mkdir upstream-remote
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g$ git init --bare upstream-remote/
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/generic/Downloads/g/upstream-remote/
```

There are already some commits in your repositories, and there is already an `upstream` remote. Setting that up...

```sh
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g$ cd A
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git remote add origin file:///home/generic/Downloads/g/upstream-remote
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ echo "file 1" > file1.txt
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git add file1.txt
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git commit -am "Initial Commit: adds file 1"
[prod (root-commit) bee891f] Initial Commit: adds file 1
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file1.txt
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git push
fatal: The current branch prod has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin prod

generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git push -u origin prod
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 224 bytes | 224.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To file:///home/generic/Downloads/g/upstream-remote
 * [new branch]      prod -> prod
branch 'prod' set up to track 'origin/prod'.

generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ cd ../B
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/B$  git remote add origin file:///home/generic/Downloads/g/upstream-remote
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/B$ git remote -v
origin  file:///home/generic/Downloads/g/upstream-remote (fetch)
origin  file:///home/generic/Downloads/g/upstream-remote (push)
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/B$ git pull origin prod
From file:///home/generic/Downloads/g/upstream-remote
 * branch            prod       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Now the two local repositories `A` and `B` are set up and have the same contents. In the meantime, somebody else might have changed the upstream repository and A and B do not yet know about it but you explicitly do not care about that. You do however care about the case where `A` has new information that `B` does not yet have.

I simulate this by creating another commit in `A` and pushing it.

```sh
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/B$ cd ../A
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ echo "file2" > file2.txt
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git add -A
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git commit -am "Second Commit."
[prod 32ec637] Second Commit.
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file2.txt
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git push origin prod
Enumerating objects: 4, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 273 bytes | 273.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To file:///home/generic/Downloads/g/upstream-remote
   bee891f..32ec637  prod -> prod
```

#### Updating `B` without pushing to origin

At this point, `A` has a branch `origin/prod` at the second commit. `B` only knows of the first.

```sh
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git log --all --oneline
32ec637 (HEAD -> prod, origin/prod) Second Commit.
bee891f Initial Commit: adds file 1
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ cd ../B
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/B$ git log --all --oneline
bee891f (HEAD -> prod, origin/prod) Initial Commit: adds file 1
```

We add a new remote to both `A` and `B`:

```sh
cd ../A
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/B$ cd ../A
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ mkdir ../temp-repo
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git init --bare ../temp-repo/
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/generic/Downloads/g/temp-repo/
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git remote add tmp /home/generic/Downloads/g/temp-repo/
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git remote -v
origin  file:///home/generic/Downloads/g/upstream-remote (fetch)
origin  file:///home/generic/Downloads/g/upstream-remote (push)
tmp /home/generic/Downloads/g/temp-repo/ (fetch)
tmp /home/generic/Downloads/g/temp-repo/ (push)
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ cd ../B
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/B$ git remote add tmp /home/generic/Downloads/g/temp-repo/
```

and push to it from A:

```sh
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/B$ cd ../A
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git push --all tmp
Enumerating objects: 6, done.
Counting objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 465 bytes | 465.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To /home/generic/Downloads/g/temp-repo/
 * [new branch]      prod -> prod
```

and fetch from there in `B`:

````sh
### Test Setup
We have two repositories and some upstream remote repository that already exist. `upstream` might be e.g. on some github server. For this answer, I will use a local folder to simulate it, but that does not matter much.

```bash
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g$ git init B
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/generic/Downloads/g/B/.git/
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g$ mkdir upstream-remote
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g$ git init --bare upstream-remote/
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/generic/Downloads/g/upstream-remote/
````

There are already some commits in your repositories, and there is already an `upstream` remote. Setting that up...

```sh
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g$ cd A
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git remote add origin file:///home/generic/Downloads/g/upstream-remote
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ echo "file 1" > file1.txt
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git add file1.txt
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git commit -am "Initial Commit: adds file 1"
[prod (root-commit) bee891f] Initial Commit: adds file 1
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file1.txt
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git push
fatal: The current branch prod has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin prod

generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git push -u origin prod
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 224 bytes | 224.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To file:///home/generic/Downloads/g/upstream-remote
 * [new branch]      prod -> prod
branch 'prod' set up to track 'origin/prod'.

generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ cd ../B
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/B$  git remote add origin file:///home/generic/Downloads/g/upstream-remote
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/B$ git remote -v
origin  file:///home/generic/Downloads/g/upstream-remote (fetch)
origin  file:///home/generic/Downloads/g/upstream-remote (push)
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/B$ git pull origin prod
From file:///home/generic/Downloads/g/upstream-remote
 * branch            prod       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Now the two local repositories `A` and `B` are set up and have the same contents. In the meantime, somebody else might have changed the upstream repository and A and B do not yet know about it but you explicitly do not care about that. You do however care about the case where `A` has new information that `B` does not yet have.

I simulate this by creating another commit in `A` and pushing it.

```sh
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/B$ cd ../A
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ echo "file2" > file2.txt
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git add -A
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git commit -am "Second Commit."
[prod 32ec637] Second Commit.
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file2.txt
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git push origin prod
Enumerating objects: 4, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 273 bytes | 273.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To file:///home/generic/Downloads/g/upstream-remote
   bee891f..32ec637  prod -> prod
```

#### Updating `B` without pushing to origin

At this point, `A` has a branch `origin/prod` at the second commit. `B` only knows of the first.

```sh
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git log --all --oneline
32ec637 (HEAD -> prod, origin/prod) Second Commit.
bee891f Initial Commit: adds file 1
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ cd ../B
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/B$ git log --all --oneline
bee891f (HEAD -> prod, origin/prod) Initial Commit: adds file 1
```

We add a new remote to both `A` and `B`:

```sh
cd ../A
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/B$ cd ../A
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ mkdir ../temp-repo
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git init --bare ../temp-repo/
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/generic/Downloads/g/temp-repo/
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git remote add tmp /home/generic/Downloads/g/temp-repo/
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git remote -v
origin  file:///home/generic/Downloads/g/upstream-remote (fetch)
origin  file:///home/generic/Downloads/g/upstream-remote (push)
tmp /home/generic/Downloads/g/temp-repo/ (fetch)
tmp /home/generic/Downloads/g/temp-repo/ (push)
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ cd ../B
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/B$ git remote add tmp /home/generic/Downloads/g/temp-repo/
```

and push to it from A:

```sh
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/B$ cd ../A
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ git push --all tmp
Enumerating objects: 6, done.
Counting objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 465 bytes | 465.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To /home/generic/Downloads/g/temp-repo/
 * [new branch]      prod -> prod
```

and fetch from there in `B`:

```sh
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/A$ cd ../B
generic@motorbrot:~/Downloads/g/B$ git fetch tmp
remote: Enumerating objects: 4, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), 253 bytes | 126.00 KiB/s, done.
From /home/generic/Downloads/g/temp-repo
 * [new branch]      prod       -> tmp/prod
```

Now you have the `tmp/prod` remote tracking branch in `B` with the second commit. It has the same state as the remote of `A` in that sense.